# Getting error android.view.InflateException when try to inflate custom view class android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I started to receive error:

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class me.markosullivan.swiperevealactionbuttons.SwipeRevealLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class me.markosullivan.swiperevealactionbuttons.SwipeRevealLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "me.markosullivan.swiperevealactionbuttons.SwipeRevealLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.jobnetzwerk
```

I'm trying to do smth like this [solution](https://github.com/MarkOSullivan94/SwipeRevealLayoutExample). Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<me.markosullivan.swiperevealactionbuttons.SwipeRevealLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    app:dragFromEdge="right">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/archive"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Info"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_inbox" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Edit"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/message_list_item_bg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_of_item"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                    android:layout_weight="15"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date_of_item"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/job_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/layout"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/jobStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/layout"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <com.lsjwzh.widget.materialloadingprogressbar.CircleProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loader"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:mlpb_arrow_height="2dp"
                app:mlpb_arrow_width="7dp"
                app:mlpb_enable_circle_background="true"
                app:mlpb_progress_stoke_width="2.5dp"
                app:mlpb_show_arrow="false" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/company_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/job_location"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ellipsize="end" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</me.markosullivan.swiperevealactionbuttons.SwipeRevealLayout>
```

I have done also class which will provide me with viewgroup but I receive this error when I try to launch my app. Why does it happen and how I can solve this error? I tried to invalidate cashes and restart AS but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your own package name when using `SwipeRevealLayout` since you're implementing an example project which declares `SwipeRevealLayout` class with its own package `me.markosullivan.swiperevealactionbuttons`, so assuming you have declared your own implementation of `SwipeRevealLayout.java` in `de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet` package, your xml usage would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet.SwipeRevealLayout
    ...
```